# Webservice does not work on a new binding in IIS

Tags: iis, server, binding, port

I have an IIS server which runs webservice that gets a list of clients from sql. It is setup on a port and works on it fine. The problem is one of the clients can't use provided link because of firewall or other issues with their company setup and doesn't want to change. I am fairly new to IIS server and internet protocols in general but I read that I can add a new binding to port 443 for https. So the link has to change from https://mywebsite.com:12345 to https://mywebsite.com. So I added a new binding but when I try to use it I get 404 Not Found page. I checked the port just to make sure and it is listened on and the service works on the other port.

EDIT
I add the screen of the site,just to make clear how it looks.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obWik.png): [site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/obWik.png)

Comment: 1) Did you add this binding to the same IIS site? 2) What's recorded in IIS log files for such 404? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-administration-management/http-status-code The substatus code is the key here to get you started.

Comment: 1) There is only one site, and I added to binding to this site. 2) For the port already running all status codes are 200. However in the logs in inetpub/logs/logfiles there are not any records with information about other ports when I try to access site from another port I do not get any information there like the request did not happen.

Comment: The screenshots you shared just contain the word 'Not-Found'. that is not giving much idea about the issue. This word does not show any information about 404 or its sub-status. Are you getting any errors in the console of the browser? try to configure a similar kind of binding with the HTTP protocol and see whether it works.

Comment: Thats all that I get in the page. In the console there is also 404 Not Found as status code, but what I can see the ip is set correctly, the same as on the working port but with the new port number. I tried adding new port to HTTP protocol but there when I try to access site It is unable due to timeout.

Comment: "However in the logs in inetpub/logs/logfiles there are not any records with information about other ports when I try to access site from another port I do not get any information there like the request did not happen" indicates that 404 might come from another machine. Escalate to your network administrators and they should take a look now.

Comment: Is this intranet site or it is available to access publically? Do you have any Firewall, AppGateway, Load Balaencer in your network? Does the port 443 is open? If possible, could you share how request come to the IIS?